# Separating input from its label across divs : AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

How do you separate a `<label>` from its `<input>` in separate `<div>`s but still have them linked?

I have an input and a label, and they are in the same div, and the functionality works.  If I move the input to a sibling div (sibling in the context of bootstrap), the toggle functionality doesn't work:

```
  <div ng-repeat="uniqJokeType in uniqJokeTypes">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">          
        <div class="type-filter-button" ng-class="jokeCssClasses(uniqJokeType)" ng-click="jokeTypeClick(uniqJokeType)">
          <label ng-bind="uniqJokeType"></label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="uniqJokeType" class="js-switch" ui-switch checked />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">          
        <!-- I want to move the <input> here, but it does not work when placed here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also, is this more of an HTML context issue, or an angular (maybe scoping?) issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `for` attribute on the `label` and an `id` on your `input` :

```
<label ng-bind="uniqJokeType" for="myInput"></label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="uniqJokeType" class="js-switch" ui-switch checked id="myInput" />
```

Comment: so an HTML issue, not an angular?

Comment: @chris Frisina : Yeah totally